# How to call a recursive closure in a new thread?

Tags: rust

[tool](https://github.com/Stebalien/tool-rs) is a grab-bag of useful functions for functional programming includes [making recursive closure](https://docs.rs/tool/0.2.1/tool/fn.fix.html), for example:

```
extern crate tool;
use tool::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let fib = fix(move |f, x| {
        if x == 0 || x == 1 {
            x
        } else {
            // `f` is `fib`
            f(x - 1) + f(x - 2)
        }
    });

    println!("{}", fib(10)); // print 55
}
```

Things I want to implement is here : [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2b1d0a825c1512a40190994a05ac1f7d)

Here's the overview: I'm defining a `function A` which take a `function B` as parameter, again the `function B` take `function C` as parameter. I need to call the `function C` in a new thread, In this case using `&dyn` keyword for the inner function gives me an error:

```
fn a(b: impl Fn(&dyn Fn() -> ()) -> ()) -> () {
 // ...
}
```

```
error[E0277]: `dyn std::ops::Fn() ->()` cannot be shared between threads safely
```

I try the syntax like below, but this gives me an another error:

```
fn a(b: impl Fn(impl Fn() -> ()) -> ()) -> () {
 // ...
}
```

```
error[E0666]: nested `impl Trait` is not allowed
 --> src/main.rs:2:21
  |
2 |     fn a(b: impl Fn(impl Fn() -> ()) -> ()) -> () {
  |             --------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------
  |             |       |
  |             |       nested `impl Trait` here
  |             outer `impl Trait`
```

Comment: My advice would be, don't. Use proper functions instead. You won't be able to ever touch that code again, because you don't understand how it works after a week or two. Even then I would be afraid to destroy the lifetimes which will occur, after you fixed the Sync thing (Just add `+ Sync` to your impls)

Comment: According to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885698/how-to-do-things-equal-to-nested-impl-trait) you can box the dyn reference.