# How to do things equal to nested `impl Trait`?

Tags: rust

`function A` which take a `function B` as parameter, again the `function B` take `function C` as parameter. I try the syntax like below, but this gives me an error:

```
fn a(b: impl Fn(impl Fn() -> ()) -> ()) -> () {
 // ...
}
```

```
error[E0666]: nested `impl Trait` is not allowed
 --> src/main.rs:2:21
  |
2 |     fn a(b: impl Fn(impl Fn() -> ()) -> ()) -> () {
  |             --------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------
  |             |       |
  |             |       nested `impl Trait` here
  |             outer `impl Trait`
```

For some reason, I can't use `&dyn` keyword:

```
fn a(b: impl Fn(&dyn Fn() -> ()) -> ()) -> () {
 // ...
}
```

Are there another ways to do this?

And I don't know why **nested `impl Trait`** cause an error.

Comment: Your second snippet with dyn works in the playground. Maybe update your compiler?

Comment: I know it works, but in my special situation, I can't use `&dyn` keyword, I need to call the function C in a new thread, otherwise it will cause an error: `cannot be shared between threads safely`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nested impl Trait doesn't work because it hasn't been specified or implemented yet. Also, because it isn't very useful given how other parts of Rust work.

`fn a(b: impl Fn(impl Fn() -> ()) -> ()) -> ()` can be written using full generic syntax as

```
fn a<B, C>(b: B) -> ()
where B: Fn(C) -> (),
      C: Fn() -> ()
```

So what does that mean? It means that `B` is something callable that takes an argument of something else callable. But the important thing here is in the concrete types. Specifically, `B` doesn't take **any** callable with a compatible signature, but specifically a `C`. What is C? Well, that's the issue. If you call `a` like this:

```
a(|f| f());
```

then `C` is the type of the lambda's parameter `f`, but that type is not known, since the parameter `f`'s type cannot be deduced from usage alone. But suppose that wasn't a problem, what would the body of `a` look like?

```
fn a<B, C>(b: B) -> ()
where B: Fn(C) -> (),
      C: Fn() -> () {
  b(|| ())
}
```

Here we attempt to call `b` passing lambda. But the lambda's type is `unnamed local lambda type`, not `C`. Since `C` was passed in from the outside, it cannot be the type of a lambda local to `a`. Simply put, unless you pass in a `C` as an additional parameter to `a`, there is *nothing* that `a` has that it could pass to `b`.

What you apparently want is for `B` to be not a function object that can be called with some `C`, but with **any** `C`. You want it to be a polymorphic function object. Rust doesn't support compile-time polymorphic function objects (the equivalent in Haskell would be a `forall a. a -> IO ()` or similar). It only supports runtime polymorphic function objects.

That's the job of `dyn`. Now you've said you can't use `&dyn`, because you want to pass the function object to another thread. So instead, use `Box<dyn>`:

```
fn a(b: impl Fn(Box<dyn Fn() -> ()>) -> ()) -> () {
 b(Box::new(|| println!("Hello")))
} 

fn main() {
    a(move |f| { f(); f(); });
}
```

Comment: As a note: whenever a function (or even a `Fn`) returns `()` you can omit that, e.g. you function a from above becomes `fn a<B, C>(b: B) where B: Fn(C), C: Fn()`

Comment: Also, here the `where` form is order of magnitudes more readable that the hypothetical nested `impl` form. Please don't try to compress your code as much as possible just because you can…

Comment: @hellow It doesn't work: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e5e5f0f52738126e103408a078f1ee7c)

Comment: *it isn't very useful given how other parts of Rust work.* I am not sure of this. I feel it may help solve [calling a recursive closure in a new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869795/how-to-call-a-recursive-closure-in-a-new-thread) out.

Comment: Your example doesn't work with `-> ()` either, so what's the point?

Comment: Ah, my bad. *you can omit that,* here the 'that' means that parentheses rather than the answer.